# Wikipedia Sitemap

Tags: wikipedia

I know how it generates the site map and all. What I need is a complete sitemap of all topics covered in wikipedia.org. Anyone know where I could get it? I have been crawling it but keep running out of space with my crawler program.

Comment: Why scrape Wikipedia when you can download the content? http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data_dumps

Comment: Wikipedia (English) has 3,696,583 articles. Think about how big that sitemap page would be ... (a few hundred MB in size)

Comment: Maybe modify your crawler program to store data to disk instead of trying to keep it all in memory?

Answer (score 3):

There is a download available for all pages in the article namespace of the English language wikipedia which is located at:

> http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/enwiki-latest-all-titles-in-ns0.gz

However they do not generate this kind of list for every language, so you need to create it yourself from the all content dump. [See the full list of all available dumps](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/) (just change the `en`-part of the URL to the language you want to see).